# openstack-nova-volume dead, how to make it alive?

Tags: openstack

When I type in openstack-status it shows the following error.

> openstack-nova-network:       dead (disabled on boot)
>   openstack-nova-volume:        dead (disabled on boot).

How do I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you need to restart the corresponding openstack service in this situation.

Let's take the openstack-nova-network as example, you can see the code of the script which control the service from /etc/init.d/openstack-nova-network

It's the script `openstack-nova-network` to do all the job for you to show the status of the service when you use the command `openstack-status`

The script `openstack-nova-network` will create some additional files when starting the service, and when the service terminates by accdient, these files will not be deleted properly.

Here is the created files:

1. A lockfile under directory: /var/lock/subsys/$prog ($prog is the name of the script, here it would be openstack-nova-network)
2. A pidfile under directory: /var/run/nova/nova-$suffix.pid ($suffix is the suffix of the script, here it would be network)

So what you should do is just to remove these 2 files, use:
`rm -f /var/lock/subsys/openstack-nova-network /var/run/nova/nova-network.pid`

After this, you can run `service openstack-nova-network status` and it would show the service is stopped and you can then run `service openstack-nova-network restart` to restart the service.

Please be note, you may still find the corresponding service unable to run, this is due to the service itself and you may check the log to see what exactly goes wrong in that service.